# How to use IUIAutomation::ElementFromPoint to get deeper web elements

Tags: microsoft-ui-automation

I would like to obtain elements on my web browser (Chrome) using the IUIAutomation::ElementFromPoint method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation-elementfrompoint

When I call the ElementFromPoint method with the point shown below, I can only get as far as the Chrome window.
But once I've used the Inspect tool, I can get to the deeper elements when I call the same method.

I am hoping to do the same with my tools.
How do you use the ElementFromPoint method to get the deepest web elements?

[Before using inspect tool.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucnDP.png)

[After using inspect tool.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH44t.png)

Answer (score 0):

Get from point only returns the topmost window around the cursor. 
To go lower you have to drill into the components and check that their bounds contain your cursor position (I know, but it’s not as slow as you’d think).

Make sure you’re using either a raw tree view walker or at least a control tree view walker.

Firefox and chrome (and I guess the new edge) require that your code Is signed to drill into web pages (otherwise you could be building something to steal card info etc) - so triple check what your program performs like when used on a machine that it wasn’t developed on , in release mode, and not on an admin account.